# C++11 could not convert std::condition_variable::wait from 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying out the examples in 'The C++ Programming Language' 4th edition and in particular, there's a description of how a `condition_variable` is used. The code snippet is as follows:

```cpp
class Message { // object to be communicated
    // ...
};
queue<Message> mqueue;    // the queue of messages
condition_variable mcond; // the variable communicating events
mutex mmutex;             // the locking mechanism


void consumer()
{
    while(true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lck{mmutex};           // acquire mmutex
        while (mcond.wait(lck)) /* do nothing */; // release lck and wait;
                                                  // re-acquire lck upon wakeup
        auto m = mqueue.front();                  // get the message
        mqueue.pop();
        lck.unlock();                             // release lck
        // ... process m ...
    }
}
```

However compilation fails on the line containing `mcond.wait(lck)` with:

`error: could not convert ‘cond.std::condition_variable::wait((* & lck))’ from ‘void’ to ‘bool’`.

The [documentation for `wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) lists it with a `void` return type. Is this an error in the book (at least I couldn't find it in the errata)? Has the standard been updated since the book came out (about two years ago)? If so, how should I use `wait` correctly in this case?

I'm using Lubuntu 14.04 64bit, my gcc version is 4.9.2, I'm compiling it in NetBeans with:

`g++ -m64 -pthread -Wextra   -c -g -Wall -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp`

EDIT: I've just realised that this has been already spotted in the [errata for the previous editions of the book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html) (which I neglected to check prior to posting this question, consulting only the 4th edition one). Still I hope it is of use to anyone who comes across it.

Comment: You should probably be using [`wait`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) with a predicate that checks for an exit condition or a non-empty queue. . wait does the loop *for you*.

Comment: I see, I'm only just starting with C++11, perhaps Stroustrup meant to put `wait_for` indeed.

Comment: I think he spaced, because `wait` will perform the loop for you if you provide  a predicate (which is extremely handy, btw). I.e. there is no need for the inner `while` loop; just `mcond.wait(lck, []() { predicate here});` or something similar. In your case that predicate would check for a force-exit flag (he doesn't have one, but should) or a non-empty queue, *both* of which being what are *really* protected by that mutex, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig Aha, I did notice examples where it comes with a lambda that supplies the predicate, but looks like `wait_for` does the job nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wait with a timeout (relative using `wait_for()` or absolute using `wait_until()`), then the return type will be `bool`.  Otherwise, it looks like a simple error in the book.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud delete while condition:

> mcond.wait(lock);

[Errata for 2nd and 3rd printings of The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html)